# Running Multiple Instances of the Same Script

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am looking into making a python script, where I have a main GUI script that can execute multiple instances of a separate script. I need these instances to be separate, so threading would not work here. I am looking into multiprocessing, but when I try to execute a function in the subscript from the main one, it only launches the main script again.

Main GUI

```
#Gui code...

import multiprocessing
import Subscript

for i in range (0, timestoruninstance):
   p = multiprocessing.Process(target=Subscript.on)
   p.start()
```

Subscript.py

```
def on():
   print("Something that will be different each script instance")
```

When running this code, the main gui instance seemingly just repeats itself rather than running multiple subscript instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your main code in a `if __name__='__main__'`. If I understand, you code is directly inside your file :

```
import multiprocessing
do_some_funcs()

def on() :
    ....
```

In python, the process read the file from the start until the end then proceed to execute your code. Starting a process create a new python executeion which is opposed to threading who shares the same object, imports and everything

To prevent your code from running twice, you should do something like this :

```
import multiprocessing

def on():
   ...

if __name__ = '__main__' : 
   do_some_funcs() ...
   p = multiprocessing.Process(target=Subscript.on)
   p.start()
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but that is not quite my issue. When I run the process execution command, it runs my main script a second time, rather than executing my second script. What am I doing wrong that would cause my main script to run twice, rather than my second script?

Comment: When you call a process, you create a new PID for process you are calling. It's like openning a new Python script manually. Before executing an only function, the whole code must be read, to set variables, import libraries, etc. Which re-execute your code from the start. If you need to share all thoses things, I can suggest you to use threads instead

Answer (score 0):

****Using the following way you can run multiple instance of same script.
Also you can add the time for the starting of next process**

```
import sys
import subprocess
import time
procs = []
inumber=int(input("Enter the number of Instance to start:"))
sleeptime=int(input("Enter the time for Next Process to start:"))
for i in range(inumber):
    proc = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, 'your script', '{}in.csv'.format(i), '{}out.csv'.format(i)])
    procs.append(proc)
    time.sleep(sleeptime)
for proc in procs:
    proc.wait()
```